# Script to delete files older than 6 months

Tags: scripting, ksh

Setting up a monthly cron job to be run via a script.

The script is to rotate a file each month as it gets too big and  rename the old one. When a file is older than six months, I wanted it to be deleted.

Looking to run this script once a month. Is that possible to get the old one deleted?

Please let me know if that isn't clear enough.

Comment: Why not just use `logrotate`?

Comment: @scottmarriott yeah, Mr Hampton's right, the functionality you described is basically the exact thing logrotate does.

Comment: Yeah I've just had a good look at logrotate makes sense cheers all

Comment: @MichaelHampton you should make that an answer.

Answer (score 33):

You could start with this:

```
find /your/file -mtime +182 -exec rm {} +
```

Where `+182` are the days quantity.

Comment: Thanks for that, might have a play with it, but I maybe logrotate might be the best option

Comment: @jordanm any ideas why this might not of worked?

Comment: ApplicationServer/logs/TestClone01 $ ls -ltr
total 3320
1048458 13 Dec 09:46 SystemOut_12.12.13_09.46.29.log
28 May 12:44 SystemOut.log.2013-05-28-12:44:52
71 30 May 08:57 SystemOut.log.2013-05-30-08:57:22
48432 30 May 09:16 SystemOut.log
no_env):/usr/websphere6/was61TE_LV2/ApplicationServer/logs/TestClone01 $ find SystemOut.log -mtime +1 -exec rm {} +
find: 0652-083 Cannot execute :: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.

Comment: I changed number of days to 1

Comment: @scottmarriott Not all versions of `find` support `+/-` for `-mtime`. What OS and version of `find` do you have?

Comment: Just a side note: using `-delete` is far more efficient than `-exec`

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `logrotate`. It's already available on most Linux systems, and many packages already have logrotate scripts pre-configured, or you can tweak them or write your own.

Answer (score 0):

> @scottmarriott Not all versions of find support +/- for -mtime. What OS and version of find do you have? – jordanm May 30 '13 at 13:04

To answer @jordanm's question, one way to do this is to enumerate over all of the found `find` results and execute something on them in the body of the `for` loop.

```bsh
# Using the general form:
for <identifier> in $(find <source-dir> -mtime +<days>) ; do <thing> ; done
 
# You could write their location to a parallel script file
echo '#!/bin/bash' > ./old.stuff
for hogfile in $(find . -mtime +182 ) ; do echo "rm $PWD/$hogfile &" >> "./old.stuff" ; done

# Make it into an executable
chmod +x ./old.stuff

# Profit
./old.stuff
```

Comment: I guess `-mtime +60` should be turn to `-mtime +180` to account woth OP's 6 months

Comment: This will horribly fail for any filename with a whitespace in it for example. You should instead look at `find` option `-exec` and/or `-print0` which results you can then feed to `xargs -0`